# Value in csv file not being displayed in original format in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

A csv file has "45029480000085" in ACCOUNT_NUMBER column. When read into Pandas using read_csv, it is getting displayed as 4.50295E+13 (scientific notation). How do I get it to display in the original format in the csv text file

Comment: Make sure you don't have NaNs in the column